# Vertical Pagination with Scollview, similar to CNN App

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am trying to implement a similar behavior of CNN App in article view, where at the end of the scroll, you can elastically pull the next article.

Does anyone know how to implement such a behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);